# Check the difference in pretrained and Finetuned model

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, llama

So I am finetuning a pretrained LLaMa2 model. I want to check if the model that I have finetuned is different from the original. I want to check the difference between base_model and model. Is there a way to check if there is a difference in weights or parameters after training?

```py
from google.colab import drive

# Mount Google Drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Path to your saved model in Google Drive
model_path_in_drive = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Mod/llama-2-7b-miniguanaco'

# Reload model in FP16 and merge it with LoRA weights
base_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
    return_dict=True,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map=device_map,
)

# Load your PeftModel from the saved checkpoint in Google Drive
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(base_model, model_path_in_drive)
model = model.merge_and_unload()
#mark_only_lora_as_trainable(lora_model)
# Reload tokenizer to save it
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"
```

I tried some methods in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-weight-quantization-2494701b9c0c) but it didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over the parameters and compare them with torch.[allclose](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.allclose.html). I used DistilBertModel for the answer, please use the respective classes from your example that are also mentioned in the comments:

```
import torch
from transformers import  DistilBertModel

# AutoModelForCausalLM in your case
base_model =  DistilBertModel.from_pretrained("distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased")
# PeftModel.merge_and_unload() in your case
finetuned_model = DistilBertModel.from_pretrained("distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english")

for base_param, finetuned_param in zip(base_model.named_parameters(), finetuned_model.named_parameters()):
  if not torch.allclose(base_param[1], finetuned_param[1]):
    print(base_param[0])
```

Output:

```
embeddings.word_embeddings.weight
embeddings.position_embeddings.weight
embeddings.LayerNorm.weight
embeddings.LayerNorm.bias
transformer.layer.0.attention.q_lin.weight
transformer.layer.0.attention.q_lin.bias
transformer.layer.0.attention.k_lin.weight
transformer.layer.0.attention.k_lin.bias
transformer.layer.0.attention.v_lin.weight
transformer.layer.0.attention.v_lin.bias
transformer.layer.0.attention.out_lin.weight
transformer.layer.0.attention.out_lin.bias
transformer.layer.0.sa_layer_norm.weight
transformer.layer.0.sa_layer_norm.bias
transformer.layer.0.ffn.lin1.weight
transformer.layer.0.ffn.lin1.bias
transformer.layer.0.ffn.lin2.weight
transformer.layer.0.ffn.lin2.bias
transformer.layer.0.output_layer_norm.weight
transformer.layer.0.output_layer_norm.bias
...
transformer.layer.5.attention.q_lin.weight
transformer.layer.5.attention.q_lin.bias
transformer.layer.5.attention.k_lin.weight
transformer.layer.5.attention.k_lin.bias
transformer.layer.5.attention.v_lin.weight
transformer.layer.5.attention.v_lin.bias
transformer.layer.5.attention.out_lin.weight
transformer.layer.5.attention.out_lin.bias
transformer.layer.5.sa_layer_norm.weight
transformer.layer.5.sa_layer_norm.bias
transformer.layer.5.ffn.lin1.weight
transformer.layer.5.ffn.lin1.bias
transformer.layer.5.ffn.lin2.weight
transformer.layer.5.ffn.lin2.bias
transformer.layer.5.output_layer_norm.weight
transformer.layer.5.output_layer_norm.bias
```

Comment: Thanks for the information!
So when I do this, nothing was printed that means the model is basically the same as pretrained, there was no actual benefit of finetuning it?

Comment: To be honest, that sounds highly unlikely. Please check your training code and that you load the correct checkpoints. In case it is possible, you can also upload the peft weights and I will have a look. @SarthakSharma